# How to filter but its not case sensitive using regexp on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I got on stackoverflow also 
       but I want to enhance it to make not case sensitive 
       or should I change the `\\b` because I think it's a match symbol.
       What should I do?

```
function filter() {
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value);
    var $els = $lbs.filter(function () {
        return regex.test($(this).text());
    });
    $lbs.not($els).hide().prev().hide();
    $els.show().prev().show();
};

input.keyup(filter).change(filter);
```

Comment: What you should do is read the manual. Start with `RegExp`.

Comment: For example, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To do a case-insensitive search, you need to have the modifier `i`.

Change

```
 var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value);
```

to

```
 var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value, "i");//Added i
```

Comment: I suggest escaping `this.value`.. `RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};` should help..You can then do `RegExp.escape(this.value)`

Comment: thanks for the answer sir... but i cant vote your answer  because i dont have enough reputation.. thank you again... hope i can help also